# Combining \chapter command and \newcommand

Tags: macros, chapters

I attach my MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\newcommand{\upper}[1]{\expandafter\MakeUppercase\expandafter{#1}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{\upper{Foo bar}}

\end{document}
```

so what I want to do is to get chapter with capitalized chapter title.
However if I use `\chapter{\upper{Foo\\ bar}}`, my MWE does not work.
Why and how can I repair that?

Comment: You should specify the uppercasing as part of the chapter formatting, you shouldn't have formatting within the `\chapter` argument.

Comment: So you want a line-break in your title? The problem stems from the fact that the title makes its way into the ToC, which is dealt with by writing content to a file... something that is fragile. Your line-breaking technique ``\\`` causes problems here. You can use ``\chapter{\upper{Foo \protect\\ bar}}`` but that would issue a line-break in the ToC also. Instead just use ``\chapter[Foo bar]{\upper{Foo \protect\\ bar}}`` if you must.

Comment: in your example code the `\expandafter` are doing nothing as once `#1` is inserted it is `\expandafter\MakeUppercase\expandafter{Foo bar}` so the `\expandafter` are applied to the token `F` which is not expandable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should avoid putting formatting in the argument (not least because it will affect tables of contents and "named" cross referencing.)

there are several ways of specifying the heading format for example the `titlesec` package:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}[block]
  {\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\thechapter}{1em}{\Huge\MakeUppercase}


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Foo\\bar}

\end{document}
```

The standard layout of the book class is obtained with

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\huge\bfseries}
  {\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename}\ \thechapter}
  {1em}
  {\Huge\MakeUppercase}


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Foo\\bar}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Not sure about the first `\MakeUppercase`

Comment: @egreg as far as I can see it does nothing too bad, it's first time I've used `titlesec` I just googled for an example and stuck `\MakeUppercase` in any argument that looked like a font spec:-) (I'll take it out though)

Comment: Well, remove it; and use `[display]` instead of `[block]`; also it should be `\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter` if one wants to emulate the standard format.

Answer (score 2):

Traditional `redefinition` of  `\@makechapterhead` and usage of an `\if....` - switch.  (One could use `\xpatchcmd` from `xpatch` as well)

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\newif\ifuppercasechaptertitle
\uppercasechaptertitletrue

\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
      \if@mainmatter
        \huge\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter
        \par\nobreak
        \vskip 20\p@
      \fi
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries \ifuppercasechaptertitle\MakeUppercase{#1}\else#1\fi\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{Foo}
\uppercasechaptertitlefalse
\chapter{Foo bar}

\end{document}
```